# Highchart js Column over overlapping

Tags: highcharts

I'm using column chart. I want a column overlap each other and set their position ascending order like this:

[image]

Comment: add some code here to justify your question.

Comment: There is no option to set the points order, so as a workaround you can create a series per point and link them together - so they behave like points from the same series. http://jsfiddle.net/dLdajow2/

Comment: exactly @morganfree .........Thanks